# How to view the original SQL statement?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

In Flask 2.3 `rows = db.execute('select * from d where id in (?)', ("(1,2)",)).fetchall()` doesn't query the data I want.

How to see the SQL it generates so I can debug it?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `echo=True` to `create_engine` and sqlalchemy will log the `SQL` it generates.  It doesn't do the interpolation itself though because the driver/dbapi usually does that.  The use of `IN` is a special case that requires placeholders for each sequence item.  You can do this like this:

```py
from sqlalchemy.sql import text, bindparam

with Session(engine) as sess:
    stmt = text('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN :ids')
    stmt = stmt.bindparams(bindparam('ids', expanding=True))
    session.execute(stmt, {"ids": [1,2]})

    # which is pretty much doing this:
    stmt = text('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (:ids_1, :ids_2)')
    session.execute(stmt, {"ids_1": 1, "ids_2": 2})
```

[sqlalchemy.sql.expression.bindparam.params.expanding](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.bindparam.params.expanding)

The logging is setup like this:

```
engine = create_engine(f"postgresql+psycopg2://{username}:{password}@/{db}", echo=True)
```

[sqlalchemy.create_engine.params.echo](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine.params.echo)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, very sorry I wrote the title wrong, actually, I didn't use sqlalchemy